# React Js: How to read a csv file? (only 4 columns out of all columns)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

I am trying to read only 4 selected columns from a csv file in react js, but i am not able to do this.

Here is my code. Can you please help? I want to select my choice of 4 columns from the file.

Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactFileReader from "react-file-reader";
class Cost extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isHidden: true,
      stats: [],
      csvData: null,
      value: "select"
    };
    this.handeSeach = this.handeSeach.bind(this);
  }

// For Upload CSV file On Table
  handleFiles = files => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
      // Use reader.result
      this.setState({
        csvData: reader.result
      });
    };
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
  };
render() {
return (
<div>

 <ReactFileReader
              multipleFiles={false}
              fileTypes={[".csv"]}
              handleFiles={this.handleFiles}
            >
              <button className="btn" id="btt">
                Import File
              </button>
            </ReactFileReader>
</div>

 );
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(Cost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [react-excel-renderer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-excel-renderer)

```
handleFiles = files => {
  //files[0] is the first file object in files array
  ExcelRenderer(files[0], (err, resp) => {
   if(err){
     console.log(err);            
   }
   else{
     this.setState({
       cols: resp.cols,
       rows: resp.rows
     });
   }
 });  
}
```

Then you can easily get required columns from cols and associated values from rows array.

Comment: I uderstand but how to select required columns in upper code ? @prasid444

Comment: In cols you can get the key for required Columns you need to extract. Then map through the rows and get the values of respective key(from cols) from each object of that row.

Answer (score 0):

you are bind diffrent function

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  isHidden: true,
  stats: [],
  csvData: null,
  value: "select"
};
//this.handeSeach = this.handeSeach.bind(this);
this.handleFiles = this.handleFiles.bind(this);
```

}